# Error connecting to SQL Anywhere 16 with php 7.1.7 (dbcapi.dll not found)

Tags: php, sqlanywhere

I run a IIS Webserver with php 7.1.7 and the propriate SQL Anywhere extension.
Anywhere Client is installed in 32bit and 64bit version.

When connecting to database with

```
$conn = sasql_connect("UID=***;PWD=***;ENG=MyEng;LINKS=tcpip{host=192.168.2.204;port=2638}");
```

I receive as error:

> The SQLAnywhere client libraries could not be loaded. Please ensure
> that dbcapi.dll can be found in your PATH environment variable.

But all seems to be fine:

- dbcapi.dll is in c:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere16\BIN32 and ...\BIN64
- both paths are included in PATH variable and also shown in phpinfo
- SQL Anywhere is shown in phpinfo output as well

What else can I check?

Regards
Florian

Answer (score 0):

actually I don't know really why, as all settings, variables, taskes are same, but after a server reboot, now message is gone and it works.

Florian